# React "obj" is read-only when dispatching

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component, which contains a form and few inputs.

```
<ModalField>
    <span>Display Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="displayName" defaultValue={data.props.display_name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
</ModalField>
<ModalField>
    <span>Phone</span>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" defaultValue={data.props.phone} onChange={this.handleChange} />
</ModalField>
```

Every time I type it changes the state with the updated value

```
handleChange(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.value 
    })
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to submit the form with an object.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const obj = {};
    obj = this.state;
    obj.username = this.props.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
    this.props.onSubmit(obj);
    this.props.onCancel();
}
```

At this point I get the error `Uncaught Error: "obj" is read-only`

How can I solve this ?
Tried few different approaches to build this object, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're initializing obj as a constant, and then trying to set it to a value. While an object initialized as a constant can add more properties (eg. obj.value = test), constants can only be set once. What you can do is do `const obj = Object.assign({}, this.state)` which will initialize obj as a copy of state.

Comment: Now I understood what was happening. Thanks !